# Create a boolean expression for current 9 bars PINESCRIPT

Tags: pine-script

I want to create a boolean expression for the current 9 bars

Example

Last 9 bars ie (close, close[1]...close[9]) = true

Last 10 bars and on (close[10]..close[n>10]) = false

how do i go about doing this?

Ta.barssince??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `math.sum()` to count the number of occurences of a condition in the given lookback period.

For instance:

```
cond = close > close[1]
cond_sum = math.sum(cond ? 1 : 0, 9)
```

`cond_sum` will tell you how many bars closed higher than the previous bar within the last 9 bars.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. But I was partially able to solve this using "barstate.islast"